# Search Bar in view when navigating back

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a search bar on a tableview(mounted on a navigatioBar), when searched for a word, the tableView filers itself and when clicked on the row, pushes to another viewController. I want to achieve this:

When I navigate back from the pushed viewController, I want to show the search bar and the keyword typed along with the keyboard.

any solution is helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: you have to make sure that your tableView is not released. so, when you come back you will get same searched table view

Comment: could you show us how did you mounted your search bar on a navigationBar? It could help us to clarify how your search bar appear or reset.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are clearing the text of searchBar when view is appearing. please check if you write this line comment it

```
self.searchBar.text=@"";
```

You are pushing your viewController so the old object is still in the memory which having the search bar with text...so after you pop from pushed viewController you will see the old object of viewController

Comment: While pushing, don't I have to hide the searchbar or else it will stay on the pushed view too and no, I haven't given that line

Comment: don't hide search bar...it does't get affected by pushed viewcontroller